# Run out of space on /home partitioned on the end of my disk

Tags: partitioning, home-directory, disk-usage

I have 4 partitions in total on my HDD in the following order:

1. `unused`  <700GB>
2. `/` <35GB>
3. `SWAP` <8GBb>
4. `/home` <150GB>

and I'm running out of space on `/home`.

Is any way to do add space from partition 1 to partition 4?

<sub>**Note:** I originally installed Ubuntu as an alternative for Windows but I ended up using it as my main OS.</sub>

Comment: I would combine `/` and `/home` into the first partition. Delete `swap`. Make partitions 2, 3 & 4 unallocated. Then create a new partition #2 of 8 GB for a new swap. That will leave an unallocated area of 50 GB that can be used in the future for one or two new primary partitions. I would consider making a new partition #3 an extended partition which could hold many logical partitions down the road if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The safest/easiest way to do this is:

1. take a full disk-to-image clone using [CloneZila](http://clonezilla.org/show-live-doc-content.php?topic=clonezilla-live/doc/01_Save_disk_image) onto an external hard drive.
2. **No, I wasn't kidding when I told you to take a full system backup!**
3. Using the [gparted live CD](http://gparted.org/livecd.php) or any recent Ubuntu boot CD go to the Gnome Partition Editor (`gparted`) and do the following:

   1. move `/` to the beginning of the disk
   2. move `swap` until after `/`
   3. move `/home` until after `swap`
   4. press <kbd>Apply</kbd>
   5. go sleep (it'll take all night)
4. now extend `/home` to however much you want.
5. run `update-grub`
6. reboot into your Ubuntu system without Windows!

Comment: And get ready to fix `grub` :)!

Comment: @Arduino_Sentinel: Thanks for reminding me! Added Step 5

Comment: **@TeheeFB** As you;re new to the site: if the answer helped, do not forget to press the ✓ to the left of this answer, meaning [the answer is useful](http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: and what should i do with clonezila after that?

Comment: Delete it if nothing goes wrong during the night or keep it around in case of catastrophic failure...  **;-)**

Comment: Hopefully you didn't need the backup???   **:-) ;-)** @TeheeFB